# MO shapes for dx2-y2 sigma bond

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals

How do the Bonding and Anti-bonding MOs of dx2-y2 sigma bonding with another dx2-y2 look like ? I mean to ask that if the sigma bond is along the x-axis then is the shape of the lobes along y-axis altered during the formation of the MOs.